# How to select one of the two sql statement with an if condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two SQL statement a year condition. Now I am trying to select one of them with this condition but I can't handle with that. The pseudo code of the result that I want is something like this;

```
begin
if p_year<2016
then 
select .....
else
select .....
end if
```

Comment: Are the two selects similar to each other?

Comment: Do you mean this: `SELECT CASE WHEN p_year < 2016 THEN 'x' ELSE 'y' END FROM your_table` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes they gives exactly same result: a name and a value.

Comment: Hi, Oto thanks for your answer. I have two different sql statements that give same type data I want select one of them with a year condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` and two mutually exclusive filters in the `WHERE` clauses:

```
SELECT name, value
FROM   table1
WHERE  p_year < 2016
UNION ALL
SELECT name, value
FROM   table2
WHERE  p_year >= 2016
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it worked for me but I want to ask to know is there any way to accomplish what I want.(not union chose one of select statement with condition)

Comment: There isn't a way to execute IF / ELSE to run different queries in SQL. There are ways of doing this but they require stored procs or other programmatic interventions